# TypeScript only compiles if previously compiled JavaScript file has been deleted

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am using Angular 2 in Visual Studio 2015, inside of an asp .net 4.5 project. When I build and run the project, JavaScript files are created correctly. However, if I make any changes to the TypeScript and recompile, the JavaScript isn't being overwritten. The only way I can get the TypeScript to recompile is by deleting the previous JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"compileOnSave": true
```

must be added to tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest opening Visual Studio as Administrator to see if it is a permissions issue, whereby VS2015 cannot overwrite your JS files.

Otherwise, right click on the **project** in your solution (not the solution itself) and select **Properties**.

You should have a tab called **TypeScript Build** as shown in the screenshot below. Ensure that you have **Compile on Save** checked.

[image: VS2015 Project Properties - TypeScript Build]

Comment: Thanks for your help. What we had to do to get this working is add "compileOnSave": true to tsconfig.json.